# Removing newline from a csv file

Tags: python, newline

I am trying to process a csv file in python that has ^M character in the middle of each row/line which is a newline. I cant open the file in any mode other than 'rU'.

If I do open the file in the 'rU' mode, it reads in the newline and splits the file (creating a newline) and gives me twice the number of rows.

I want to remove the newline altogether. How?

Comment: `dos2unix` is what you want.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Note that, as [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) say:

> *csvfile* can be any object which supports the iterator protocol and returns a string each time its `next()` method is called — file objects and list objects are both suitable.

So, you can always stick a filter on the file before handing it to your `reader` or `DictReader`. Instead of this:

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'rU') as myfile:
    for row in csv.reader(myfile):
```

Do this:

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'rU') as myfile:
    filtered = (line.replace('\r', '') for line in myfile)
    for row in csv.reader(filtered):
```

That `'\r'` is the Python (and C) way of spelling `^M`. So, this just strips all `^M` characters out, no matter where they appear, by replacing each one with an empty string.

---

> I guess I want to modify the file permanently as opposed to filtering it.

First, if you want to modify the file before running your Python script on it, why not do that from outside of Python? `sed`, `tr`, many text editors, etc. can all do this for you. Here's a GNU sed example:

```
gsed -i'' 's/\r//g' myfile.csv
```

But if you want to do it in Python, it's not that much more verbose, and you might find it more readable, so:

First, you can't really modify a file in-place if you want to insert or delete from the middle. The usual solution is to write a new file, and either move the new file over the old one (Unix only) or delete the old one (cross-platform).

The cross-platform version:

```
os.rename('myfile.csv', 'myfile.csv.bak')
with open('myfile.csv.bak', 'rU') as infile, open('myfile.csv', 'wU') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(line.replace('\r'))
os.remove('myfile.csv.bak')
```

The less-clunky, but Unix-only, version:

```
temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
with open('myfile.csv', 'rU') as myfile, closing(temp):
    for line in myfile:
        temp.write(line.replace('\r'))
os.rename(tempfile.name, 'myfile.csv')
```

Comment: I guess I want to modify the file permanently as opposed to filtering it. Your code filters it, but is there a way for instance to open the file and just remove the ^M and close it, hence permanently modifying it? For instance in the above, once I print the rows, I do see the newlines. Not sure what I as missing.  I mean I can always open the file in rU and create a new file and append the rows to it creating 1 row for 2 rows in the original. Many thanks.

Comment: @dqr: I'm not sure I understand your followup, but I'll try to update the answer.

Comment: @abarnert: I get the following error when I run the python version of your solution: ValueError: universal newline mode can only be used with modes starting with 'r'.  Do you know why?