# How to search and concatenate cells based on search results

Tags: excel, vba

first off, I'm still learning excel VBA and it seems i'm trying to bite more than I can chew here. I tried to search for my problem but I cant find issues that close to mine.

So, i have a csv dataset that looks like this:

```
date,"0000000000","SAO","32","Description","5000","REF"
date,"0000000000","SAO","32","Reversal from 
\nDescription","-5000","REF"
date,"0000000000","SAO","32","Description","10000","REF"
```

What I want the data to look like is this:

```
date,"0000000000","SAO","32","Description","5000","REF"
date,"0000000000","SAO","32","Reversal from Description","-5000","REF"
date,"0000000000","SAO","32","Description","10000","REF"
```

Manually it's so simple, but, there's more than 3000 lines that needs to be corrected, so I need to automate this problem. I tried recording macros but it didn't work.

The steps needed to be done is:
1. search for "\n"
I believe this could be done with this?

```
set result = Find(What:="\n", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

2. copy the search result values
3. paste the search result values in the cell before the search result so it looked like this

```
date,"0000000000","SAO","32","Description","5000","REF"
date,"0000000000","SAO","32","Reversal from \nDescription","-5000","REF"

date,"0000000000","SAO","32","Description","10000","REF"
```

4. delete the blank cells.
5. delete the \n from "Reversal from \nDescription" so it doesn't get processed again
6. start from 1 again.

I don't have the knowledge on how to do this, please help?

Thank you

Comment: Hello. This links will help you, i think. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390123/removing-newline-from-a-csv-file and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39447740/how-to-remove-newline-characters-from-csv-file

Comment: You are going to have to replace both the `\n` and also the `newline` character (which might be a `cr`, `lf` or both depending on how the csv was generated..

Comment: Thank you for the link @AlexeyC, I don't have knowledge of phyton yet, but I will try to understand it.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld If I understand correctly, Instead of steps 2-5, I could just replaced "cr\n" or "lf\n" or crlf\n" with " "? Sadly I don't know how the csv was generated